# Python Error on while True loop

Tags: python

```
total = 0                                                   
print ("Enter first number")
num1 = input()
print ("Enter 1)Add 2)Minus 3)Multiply 4)Divide")
choice = input()

while True:
    print("Wrong Answer Pick Again")
    print("Enter 1)Add 2)Minus 3)Multiply 4)Divide")
    choice = input()
    if choice => 1 and choice =< 4:
        break

if choice == 1:
  print ('Enter second number')
  num2 = input()
  total = num1 + num2 

elif choice == 2:
  print ('Enter second number')
  num2 = input()
  total = num1 - num2
elif choice == 3:
  print ('Enter second number')
  num2 = input()
  total = num1 * num2
elif choice == 4:
  print ('Enter second number')
  num2 = input()
  total = num1 / num2

print("Total")
print (total)
```

I`m getting a syntax error on the "if choice => 1 and choice =<4:" can some one please help. I have tried so many different things and nothing have worked.

Comment: `if choice >= 1 and choice <= 4:` or just `if 1 <= choice <= 4:`

Comment: you need to reverse the symbols : `>=`

Comment: Thanks a lot has been bugging me for a while.

Comment: `choice in [1,2,3,4]` would be better. And your code is still going to fail because `input()` returns everything as a string. Also, the loop always prints "Wrong Answer Pick Again" at least once, even if the user inputs a correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should work for you :

```
total = 0                                                   

print ("Enter 1)Add 2)Minus 3)Multiply 4)Divide")
choice = int(input())

for _ in range(int(input("total test cases"))):


    if choice >= 1 and choice <= 4:
        if choice == 1:
            print ("Enter first number")
            num1 = int(input())
            print ('Enter second number')
            num2 = int(input())
            total = num1 + num2
            print("Total is: ",total)
            choice=int(input("enter choice again"))

        elif choice == 2:
            print ("Enter first number")
            num1 = int(input())
            print ('Enter second number')
            num2 = int(input())
            total = num1 - num2
            print("Total is: ",total)
            choice=int(input("enter choice again"))

        elif choice == 3:
            print ("Enter first number")
            num1 = int(input())
            print ('Enter second number')
            num2 = int(input())
            total = num1 * num2
            print("Total is: ",total)
            choice=int(input("enter choice again"))

        elif choice == 4:
            print ("Enter first number")
            num1 = int(input())
            print ('Enter second number')
            num2 = int(input())
            total = num1 / num2
            print("Total is: ",total)
            choice=int(input("enter choice again"))
    else:
        print("wrong number entered")
        choice=int(input("enter again"))
```

Note:If you find this answer helpful you can mark this answer correct

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestions I will use them in my code.

Comment: @Adam I have edited my answer so tat the script can work according to your question